# Android: Align Parent Bottom + Bottom margin programaticamente

Tags: android, android-layout

Alguém sabe como posso, programaticamente, adicionar um RelativeLayout alinhado na parte inferior do pai e incluir uma margem ou padding na parte inferior desse mesmo RelativeLayout?

Ex.:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Igor, você precisa especificar qual a classe do pai, porque dependendo da escolha, pode variar a subclasse de `LayoutParams` a se usar e a técnica a se usar também. Em geral você pode usar o atributo `layout_gravity` como `bottom|right` programaticamente no `LayoutParams` e para adicionar margem precisa ser num `MarginLayoutParams` e padding diretamente na `View`.

Comment: Classe pai é RelativeLayout também

Comment: Igor, irei fazer um teste aqui e se funcionar posto uma resposta. Irá contruir o elemento programaticamente ou irá inflá-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para adicionar programaticamente utilizei o seguinte código:

```
RelativeLayout r = new RelativeLayout(this);

// O padding eh setado direto na View
r.setPadding(100, 100, 100, 100);

// Recupero o pai
RelativeLayout rl = ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent));

// Soh para dar contraste com o background
rl.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

// Crio um LayoutParams para posicionar e dar tamanho para a View
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400);
// ou
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);

// Setando as margens
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 32, 32);

// Adiciono uma regra para alinhar o filho ao fundo do pai
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
// Adiciono as regras para alinha o filho no final do pai
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
// Suporte para layout RTL
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);

// Adiciono a View no pai, especificando o LayoutParams
rl.addView(r, lp);
```

É claro que para dar o efeito esperado o pai precisa ocupar todo o espaço, usando o `MATCH_PARENT` em relação a `Window`.

Um exemplo como ficou em meu dispositivo:

[image: Exemplo de alinhamento programático]

Comment: ainda não funcionou no meu, meu layout pai também é feito programaticamente.

Comment: Se puder, poste o código que usa para gerar ele, o exemplo que fiz foi com o pai inflado pela `Activity`.

Comment: fui verificar o pai do pai desse layout e vi que estava WRAP_CONTENT, então funcionou. Obrigado @Wakim